# using sql reader to check for nulls when setting multiple values

Tags: sql

I have a sql command that is picking up a row in my DB but sometimes one of the datetime values may be null.

example:

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    List<AdmissionsVm> appDetailsOut = new List<AdmissionsVm>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        appListOut.Add(new AdmissionsVm
                        {
                            Parish = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(40)),
                            CofE = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetValue(41)),
                            OtherFaith = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(42)),
                            PrefSiblingName1 = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(43)),
                            if (!reader.GetValue(44).IsDbNull){SiblingDateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(44))}
                            SiblingGender = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(45))
                        });
                    }
                }
```

I am actually bringing back a lot of details but when the siblingdateofbirth is null, i cant seem to check it as i am getting errors with fields that have been added afterwards

any help would be appreciated

Comment: first thing: use reader.GetDateTime instead of converting the value to DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Its often better to specify the column name instead of the column position because if the query for some reason changes the order in which its returning columns, you may need to change the params of all the GetValue calls.

To check for null try something like this

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("YourColumnNameForPosition44")))
          {SiblingDateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("YourColumnAgain"))}
```